# How to make a random m3u playlist from all files in subfolders?

Tags: mp3, playlists

I want to create a random playlist for my entire music collection of 90,000 tracks. - i.e.generate a single m3u playlist containing every mp3 in every subfolder of my music folder, and present the list in random order.
Any suggestions for how I can do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, set up the list (you only need to do this when you add/delete files) :

```
find Music -type f -print >files.list
wc -l files.list >files.list.nlines
```

Then, to pick a random one,

```
line_number=$(echo "$(cat files.list.nlines) * $RANDOM / 32767" | bc -q)
file_to_play="$(sed -n ${line_number}p files.list)"
```

Comment: Thanks. The first command works well, but generates a  list of all files - how would I adapt it to list just the mp3's? I can't get the 2nd command to work. When I run it I get a ">" prompt. Is there a syntax error?

Comment: @user1175461 Fixed.

Comment: You can use the `shuf` command instead (`shuf -o files.list files.list`).

Comment: Thanks  - wow that shuf command worked unfeasibly quickly!

Comment: How can I adapt the first command to include only mp3 files?

Comment: OK I worked it out - added -name '*.mp3' as a parameter